# Interpreting the memory address in fortran 90

Tags: fortran90, memory-address

Is there any way to interpret the hex address directly/indirectly in fortran(90). For instance, some times I get memory segmentation issue followed by `Failing at address: 0x1fffffff8`. A more complete message is something like this:

```
[amir-desktop] *** Process received signal ***
[amir-desktop] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[amir-desktop] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[amir-desktop] Failing at address: 0x1fffffff8
[amir-desktop] [ 0] /lib/libpthread.so.0(+0xf8f0) [0x2af5efcb08f0]
[amir-desktop] [ 1] test.exe(__box_mod_MOD_constructlist+0x35c) [0x44052c]
[amir-desktop] [ 2] test.exe(__box_mod_MOD_box_move+0x72) [0x443372]
[amir-desktop] [ 3] test.exe() [0x44c81b]
[amir-desktop] [ 4] test.exe(main+0x1d) [0x41336d]
[amir-desktop] [ 5] /lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x2af5f59a9c8d]
[amir-desktop] [ 6] test.exe() [0x41391d]
```

Is it possible to realize that this address is related to a specific variable, maybe by a simple print statement. I know that `loc` function prints an integer regarding the address of the variable (Another question arise if they are convertible to hex type address). I would guess that it might be possible to use debugger for that purpose. I would appreciate if some one can comment on this (and some suggestion) as well.

I am currently using gfortran 4.6. under linux distribution.

Thanks

Comment: side note: you can write any integer (incl. result of `loc()`) in hex by using explicit format `print '(Z0)', loc(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
[amir-desktop] [ 1] test.exe(__box_mod_MOD_constructlist+0x35c) [0x44052c]
```

tells you that the error was in the function `constructlist` in the `box_mod` module. I would start looking there for any obvious errors first.

Try compiling with the following flags:

```
gfortran -g -fbacktrace -fbounds-check -Wall test.f90
```

These will (in order): turn on debugging symbols, print out backtraces, check array bounds and print most warnings about unsafe code during compilation.

If that still doesn't solve your problem, you can use `gdb` on a core dump. This is a record of the state of your program when it crashed. You'll need to enable core dumps first by running `ulimit -c unlimited`  in your terminal. Next, run your code - you should get an error like `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` - and it will create a file named `core` or `core.pid`, where `pid` is a number. Finally, you can run `gdb` like so:

`gdb ./test.exe core.pid`

It will print a whole bunch of information and then leave you with a `(gdb)` prompt. Run a stack trace with `bt` to see what happened when your program crashed. `quit` will exit gdb.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Actually I solved the issue by extensive using of print statement throughout the code. However, I intentionally retained the bug and after including the flags you mentioned, it gave me a good hint about the issue in the code, without further producing core dumps. Also, I put another bug to be able to follow the procedure you explained but again after printing out "Backtrace for this error:", it froze. Could you refer me to some documents possibly with examples in that regard.